# simple rust crate function integer/float error

Tags: rust

I am trying to run following rust source file as script using [cargo-script](https://github.com/DanielKeep/cargo-script):

```rust
// cargo-deps: statistical

extern crate statistical;
use statistical::*;
fn main() {
    let alist = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
    println!("mean of list: {}", mean(&alist)); // not working
}
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
$ cargo script mystats.rs 
    Updating crates.io index
   Compiling mystats v0.1.0 (/home/abcde/.cargo/script-cache/file-mystats-6e38bab8b3f0569c)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `{integer}: num_traits::float::Float` is not satisfied
 --> mystats.rs:7:31
  |
7 |     println!("mean of list: {}", mean(&alist));  // not working
  |                                  ^^^^ the trait `num_traits::float::Float` is not implemented for `{integer}`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <f32 as num_traits::float::Float>
            <f64 as num_traits::float::Float>
  = note: required by `statistical::mean`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: Could not compile `mystats`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
internal error: cargo failed with status 101
```

How can this integer/float problem be solved?

Comment: Tbh the function signature of `mean` is a little bit quirky, because I see no reason why they can't accept something like `fn mean<I: Float>(p: impl Iterator<Item = I>) -> I;` and you were not forced to pass a slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the mean function wants to return the same type as the one in the slice. If it allowed integers, you could be able to compute the mean of [0, 1] and it would return 0 (1 / 2 as an integer). That's why statistical forces you to use floatting types.

The following works on my machine

```
// cargo-deps: statistical
extern crate statistical;
use statistical::*;

fn main() {
    let alist = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
    let alist_f64: Vec<f64> = alist.iter().map(|x| f64::from(*x)).collect();
    println!("mean of list: {}", mean(&alist_f64));
}
```

It prints this

```
mean of list: 30
```

Note that the `collect` function will make a copy of the array. There would be a better way if the mean function would take an iterator as parameter but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: <pedant on>It's usually better to do [`f64::from (*x)` instead of `*x as f64`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#cast_lossless).

Comment: Yes. You could refer to the error message *"the trait `num_traits::float::Float` is not implemented for `{integer}`"*, and explain that `Float` is obviously not implemented for an integer :)